# How to combine world environment post processing with custom post processing shader in a 3D world, Godot 4.0

Tags: godot, post-processing, godot-shader-language

I am trying to use the in-built post processing effects attached to a Camera3D while also applying a custom post processing effect to run in combination with the other effects.

I have read tutorials on how to create custom post processing effects, like the one found on the [official docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/shaders/advanced_postprocessing.html). It tells me to create a MeshInstance with a QuadMesh (well, in Godot 4.0, it is actually now a PlaneMesh) and transform it into clip space.

For one, the transformation explained in the docs did not work, the quad just disappeared when I applied the following vertex shader and applied a large value to `extra_cull_margin`:

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode cull_disabled, unshaded;

void vertex() {
    POSITION = vec4(VERTEX, 1.0); 
}
```

Then, I managed to work around this by actually manually rotating the plane such that it faces the camera and with a Z offset of something small but larger than the camera near field.
[image: Quad and Camera]
[image: Camera view]

The issue is that with this plane in front, none of the world environment post processing effects work. Now, I think it might work better if I get the transform working of the quad to clip space, but it doesn't work for me.

**Has anyone tried this yet for Godot 4.0 beta 1?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so reading up on how to do this in general, I stumbled upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588875/whats-the-best-way-to-draw-a-fullscreen-quad-in-opengl-3-2).

Based on the answer from derhass, I wrote the following vertex shader code:

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode cull_disabled, unshaded;

const vec2 vertices[3] = {vec2(-1,-1), vec2(3,-1), vec2(-1, 3)};

void vertex() {
    POSITION = vec4(vertices[VERTEX_ID],0.0,1.0);
}
```

This draws a triangle and it also transforms it successfully into clip space.

Now the world environment effects are working together with the custom post processing shader:

[With shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNvWR.png)

[Without shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFdKi.png)