# Isn't a quad always composed of 4 vertex?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, vertex, text-rendering

I'm getting into OpenGL. I'm following [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com) and I reached the text rendering part, where I read (at the end of `In Practice` > `Text Rendering` > `Shaders` section)

> The 2D quad requires 6 vertices of 4 floats each, so we reserve 6 * 4 floats of memory. Because we'll be updating the content of the VBO's memory quite often we'll allocate the memory with GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW.

So far I was thinking of a quad as a pair of triangles, four vertex. How a quad can require 6 vertex?

Comment: Do you believe one triangle has 3 vertices?  The code accompanying your quote defines _two_ of those.  You can also see in the code that the two triangles have two points in common.

Comment: Oh, maybe I got it, `3 + 3 = 6`. I was thinking in the index case, where we only need 4 vertex to define a quad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a quad contains 2 triangles it can take 6 vertices, 2 vertices will be the duplicated in this case.

Alternatively, you can use 4 vertices and [`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives). All vertices will be unique, no duplicates.

Alternatively, there is a [trick](https://rauwendaal.net/2014/06/14/rendering-a-screen-covering-triangle-in-opengl/) with **only one** triangle, 3 vertices only. Vertex shader would look like:

```
out vec2 texCoord;
 
void main()
{
    float x = -1.0 + float((gl_VertexID & 1) << 2);
    float y = -1.0 + float((gl_VertexID & 2) << 1);
    texCoord.x = (x+1.0)*0.5;
    texCoord.y = (y+1.0)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(x, y, 0, 1);
}
```

And a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588875/whats-the-best-way-to-draw-a-fullscreen-quad-in-opengl-3-2) what pros and cons have these methods.