# How the vertex shader is passing to the fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

In the following vertex shader I am not able to understand what output does the lines 1 and 2 give out.

```c
#version 450
out vec2 texcoord;
    
void main()
{
   texcoord    = vec2((gl_VertexID << 1) & 2, gl_VertexID & 2);  // Line 1
   gl_Position = vec4(texcoord * 2.0f - 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   // Line 2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a method to define a **full-screen quad using a single triangle**.

A full-screen quad can be drawn as two triangles, but also as one large triangle which contains the quad. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588875/whats-the-best-way-to-draw-a-fullscreen-quad-in-opengl-3-2) for more information.

In your example, the `glDrawArrays` function will be instructed to draw 3 vertices, causing the vertex shader to run 3 times for `gl_VertexID` 0, 1, and 2. This produces the following data:

```
gl_VertexID 0: texcoords(0.0F, 0.0F), gl_Position(-1.0F, -1.0F)
gl_VertexID 1: texcoords(2.0F, 0.0F), gl_Position( 3.0F, -1.0F)
gl_VertexID 2: texcoords(0.0F, 2.0F), gl_Position(-1.0F,  3.0F)
```

This defines a triangle in screenspace coordinates, going from the bottom left of the screen, then to the right ("beyond the screen"), and finally going to the top left ("beyond the screen"). The top-right corner of the quad sits on the hypotenuse of the triangle . The UV-coordinates are adjusted accordingly. The excess parts of the triangle will be clipped before rendering the quad's fragments.

The **exact computations happen as follows**:

We may assume this code is designed to only work for `gl_VertexID` 0, 1 and 2.

The bitwise AND in `gl_VertexID & 2` clears all bits except for the second one, so the value 2 is kept at 2, any other value becomes 0. With a `<< 1` shift first, only `gl_VertexID == 1` becomes 2 and any other value becomes 0.

For the `gl_Position`, the texcoords are mapped from the range [0, 2] to [-1, 3] to obtain the triangle vertex' positions.

Answer (score 1):

**Line 1** calculate texture coordinates (U,V in the range of 0..1 in the texture image).
It fill's the `texcoord` variable, defined as an **output** from the shader in this line:

```
out vec2 texcoord;
```

**Line 2** calculates the vertex position, and updates the predefined global variable `gl_Position`. This variable is then availavle as an outout from the shader.

More about opengl predefined global variables: [Built-in Variable (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)).
More about `gl_position`: [documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_Position.xhtml).

**Regarding the content of the output:**
Looks like the U texture coordinate (`(gl_VertexID << 1) & 2`) is either 0 or 1 depending of the least significant bit in `gl_VertexID`, and the V texture coordinate (`gl_VertexID & 2`) is either 0 or 1 depending on the 2nd bit of `gl_VertexID`.
`gl_Position` `x` is either 1 if `U` is 1 and -1 otherwise. Similarly `y` is dependant on `V`.
I cannot say why it is required by the application to be that way.